# Persisting RabbitMQ Queues and Data on Azure Container Instance

Tags: azure, docker, rabbitmq

I've successfully deployed RabbitMQ Bitnami docker to run as container instance in my Azure subscription, and I'm able to send messages to a queue which I defined via the RabbitMQ management web ui.
Thing is, that once i'm restarting the container instance, all messages **and queues** are gone.
I defined a file share under the same resource group, and invoked the following Azure CLI command to create the instance and "bind" it to the file share: 
`az container create -g learning1 --name rabbitmq-instance1 --image dbmregistry1.azurecr.io/bitnami/rabbitmq:latest --cpu 1 --memory 1 --ports 80 5672 15672 --dns-name-label db-rabbit1 --azure-file-volume-share-name dbshare1 --azure-file-volume-account-name {STORAGE-NAME} --azure-file-volume-account-key {KEY} --azure-file-volume-mount-path /data` 
But it seems not to be sufficient. In management web api it looks like that: 
[RabbitMQ node image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCgmb.png)

Appreciate any advice of what might be missing.

Comment: Check the resource utilization and increase (--cpu 1 --memory 1) CPU, Memory values.

Comment: Did this work at all. I am having same issue